# Does SAPI recognize SSML 'pitch' element?

Tags: c#, sapi

I'm using C# System.Speech.Synthesis and cannot get the 'pitch' SSML control element to make any effect when used with semi-tones or Herzes. The following code works OK and the pitch is changed (when controlled with codes `low`, `high`, `x-high` etc.):

```
SpeechSynthesizer synth = new SpeechSynthesizer();
PromptBuilder pb1 = new PromptBuilder();
string high = "<prosody pitch=\"x-high\"> This is extra high pitch. </prosody >";
pb1.AppendSsmlMarkup( high );
synth.Speak( pb1 );
```

But when the SSML string is defined as:

```
string high = "<prosody pitch=\"+4st\"> This is extra high pitch. </prosody >";
```

or

```
string high = "<prosody pitch=\"+200Hz\"> This is extra high pitch. </prosody >";
```

There is no any change in pitch. Is there a way to use '+4st' or '+200Hz' or similar form (maybe with percents or with absolute values) to control the pitch more precisely than with several predefined levels?

Comment: It definitely works on my machine (Win 8.1), "-100Hz" vs "0Hz" vs "100Hz" all have different pitches.  It however supports just three of them, no doubt a restriction in the voice implementation.

Comment: What @HansPassant said.   You need to distinguish between SAPI and the TTS engine.   In particular, which voice are you using?

Comment: Did you find any solution for to issue?